# Canvas drag on mouse movement

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to build a canvas that i can drag using mouse movement. And I'm doing something wrong that i cannot understand cause seems to work at first and then there is like an incremental error that make the canvas move too fast.

Considering the following code,

```
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


  function draw() {
    context.fillRect(25, 25, 100, 100);
  }

  function clear() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
  var drag = false;
  var dragStart;
  var dragEnd;
  draw()
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    dragStart = {
      x: event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft,
      y: event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop
    }

    drag = true;

  })

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    if (drag) {
      dragEnd = {
        x: event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft,
        y: event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop
      }
      context.translate(dragEnd.x - dragStart.x, dragEnd.y - dragStart.y);
      clear()
      draw()
    }

  })

}
```

live example on Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/j8QCxwDzXJZN2DKszKwm.

Can someone help me to understand what piece I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem your code has is that each time you move the rectangle blablabla px relative to the dragStart position, the `translate()` method is not based on dragStart position, but your current position.

To fix this, you should add the following after calling the `translate` method:

```
dragStart = dragEnd;
```

So that your position is also based on current mouse position.