# Canvas: Zooming and Panning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am struggling to make this canvas drawing to zoom in and out and panning it. There are some examples with panning and zooming images but my case is different and I don't know what or how should I do it in my case cause it is not images. I would appreciate any tips or any library that you could suggest?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        canvas{border:#666 1px solid;}

    </style>
  <script type="application/javascript" language="javascript">
  window.onload=draw;//execute draw function when DOM is ready
    function  draw(){
        //assign our canvas element to a variable
          var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas1');
        //create the html5 context object to enable draw methods
          var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.arc(150, 200, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
              ctx.fill();

              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(150,200);
              ctx.lineTo(230,75);
              ctx.stroke();

              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.arc(230, 75, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
              ctx.fill();

              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(230,75);
              ctx.lineTo(300,200);
              ctx.stroke();

              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.arc(300,200, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
              ctx.fill();

              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(300,200);
              ctx.lineTo(150,200);
              ctx.stroke();

              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(300,200);
              ctx.lineTo(225,300);
              ctx.stroke();

              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.arc(225,300, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
              ctx.fill();





          //fillStyle (r, g, b, alpha)
            //ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,200,0,1)";
          //fillRect (X, Y, Width, height)
            //ctx.fillRect(36,10,220,120);
    }
    </script>
</head>
  <body>
      <center>
      <canvas id="canvas1" width="800" height="600" ></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a screenshot of my drawing that I am trying to make it zoom in mouse cursor:

[canvas drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjuNR.png)

Comment: How to zoom at mouse coord https://stackoverflow.com/a/45528455/3877726 How to zoom, pan, with bounds constraints https://stackoverflow.com/a/44015705/3877726 Both use a version of object called view. Second is more detailed and will work for any type of canvas rendering.

Comment: @Blindman67 thanks man, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Panzoom (https://github.com/timmywil/panzoom) says that it supports panning and zoom basically any HTMLElement, including a canvas:

> Panzoom uses CSS transforms to take advantage of hardware/GPU
> acceleration in the browser, which means the element can be anything:
> an image, a video, an iframe, a **canvas**, text, WHATEVER.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with buttons instead of "drag to pan", you can use [`translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate) method for panning. You can also use [`save()` and `restore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations#Translating) methods or following approach. Here's what I used in similar situation, but I've used buttons:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
   scale = 1;
   canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); //Replace with id of your canvas
   ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   ctx.translate(150, 75);
   drawcanvas();
} 
  
function drawcanvas() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  //call to function(s) which draws necessary things
  //..
  //..
  drawarrow(ctx);
  ctx.stroke(); 
}
    
function clearcanvas() {
  let current_transform = ctx.getTransform();
  ctx.setTransform(1.1, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width*scale, canvas.height*scale);
  ctx.setTransform(current_transform);
}

function zoomin() {
  clearcanvas();
  scale = 1.1;
  ctx.scale(scale, scale);
  drawcanvas();
}

function zoomout() {
  clearcanvas();
  scale = 1.0/1.1;
  ctx.scale(scale, scale);
  drawcanvas();
}

function moveleft() {
  clearcanvas();
  ctx.translate(-10, 0);
  drawcanvas();
}

function moveright() {
  clearcanvas();
  ctx.translate(10, 0);
  drawcanvas();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="c" class="container h-75"  style="border: solid 1px blue"></canvas><br />
  <button onclick="zoomin()" class="btn btn-dark">+</button>
  <button onclick="zoomout()" class="btn btn-dark">-</button>
  <button onclick="moveleft()" class="btn btn-dark"><-</button>
  <button onclick="moveright()" class="btn btn-dark">-></button>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** I found better solution for panning problem, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142308/canvas-drag-on-mouse-movement) and it's accepted answer.